# Why is Vishnu not taking avatar?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Non-vedic people have gained lots of power in Aryavrata (India) . Population of Hindus is decreasing rapidly. It is high time he should take at least ansh-avatar to save us.

In the past PusyaMitra Sunga (in about 200 BCE) and Adi Shankaracharya (in about 700 AD) eliminated Buddhism from India and reestablished Hinduism. (Maybe there were avataras , not sure though)
I think current situation is similar.

Comment: Firstly, who are you to determine when should Bhagavana take avatara or not ? Secondly, Kalki will appear at the end the end of Kaliyuga, whose duration is 4,32,000 years. Around 5100 years of Kaliyuga has elapsed as we speak. Real degradation of Sanatana dharma is expected to begin another 4900 years later.

Comment: Avatar only takes place to restore cosmic balance. The ongoing adharma does not qualify

Comment: These prophecies like when god will take avatar have already been made by scriptures. So, it is already told to us that when god will take avatar, what will happen, etc. Now, we will have Kalki Avatar and you can read Kalki Purana for that :)

Comment: vishnu taking avatar every Halloween.  but you are not ready for His presence...

Comment: btw, Vishnu has taken many avatars in Kali Yug already, and probably take many more in future. Venkateshwara, Vittala have taken form of their devotees to do their menial tasks when the devotees where unable to. Kalki is just the predominant/famous one. Same in previous yugas too - his avatars are not limited to 10, or 24 or any number. @AnubrataBit