# Why are unvedic civilization prospering in present time?

Tags: vedas, kali-yuga

Unvedic and anti-vedic  civilization are prospering in current time. While vedic civilization is becoming weak .
Why is it like this ?
Is there any scripture where is written that vedic civilization will become extremely weak and anti-vedic civilization will gain lots of power in Kaliyug.

Kaliyug started about 5000 years ago. And at present anti-vedic people have gained lots of power.

Is the demon Kali assiting anti-vedic people ?

Comment: Similar - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53087/why-does-vishnu-not-taking-avatar

Comment: In Brahmavaivarta Purana, it is said that in lieu to testing the chastity of the daughter of a king named Kedara, Dharma assumed the form of a brahmin & gave her an indecent proposal. Furious at that, she uttered the words 'Kshayi Bhava' (Be reduced) thrice to him. Her power of chastity was so great that even Brahma was unable to relieve Dharma from her curse. As a consequence, dharma declines in Kaliyuga.

Comment: Most scriptures unanimously agree that dharma propounded by the rshis in general will decline in Kaliyuga & traces of it will remain until 10,000 years of Kaliyuga. Secondly, Kali isn't the Hindu equivalent of the Biblical Satan. He is described to be the son of Brahma & Savitri.

Comment: Yes this is happening and I'm very sad about it.☹️ In the puranas, it is written that people will not follow and accept vedas and their teachings. So, maybe that's why people are not following vedic path.